# Background not show in LinearLayout in version 4.2

Tags: android, android-layout, background, background-image

my problem is that in version 4.2 the background in LinearLayout not showing, but in previous version it showing. I put the background like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

I was just having the exact same problem. What fixed it for me was making sure I had the proper versions in the proper drawable-xxxx folder. For example...

If your image is in `res/drawable` but not in any other folder like `res/drawable-hdpi`, `res/drawable-xhdpi`, etc make sure you create a version appropriate for each of the screen sizes you are supporting and include that version in the corresponding drawable folder.

After I did that my bg drawable started showing up.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it helps someone..I had a problem too with version 4.1.1 and everything I do was to set background programmatically

```
myLayout.setBackground(yourDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any problem with the syntax you are using. May be you are having some other problem. My advice would be to-

- Try cleaning the project and run it again.
- Check if you have the image named 'image.xxx' in your drawable folder.
- Check if you are setting background of the correct layout.

or perhaps you can post some more code so that we can answer you more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Above answer, check that the name of the image in drawable folder is in lower-case. All the drawables must have lower-case names.